# Getting Song Stream Counts from Streaming Services to Auto-Update in Excel Sheet

Tags: python, excel, analytics, spotify

This is a bit of a bigger idea question, but I'm working on a project in which it would be really helpful to have a few columns in an Excel sheet that auto-update daily with the number of streams that a bunch of songs (also housed in spreadsheet) have on different streaming services (different columns for Spotify/Apple music/YouTube/etc.). What would be the best way to go about this?

My first thought was to use these services' APIs along with Openpyxl to write some Python scripts that accomplish the task listed above. I wrote one that works for Spotify which I'll post below so you can get an idea of where I'm at (it finds the songs' popularities from a column full of the Spotify song ids that I got from another script I wrote).

The Apple Music API seems to require a paid subscription to the Apple development program, and I have found some other APIs that seem like they might do the job (ie https://docs.songstats.com/). But all in all though I guess my question is are these APIs the best way to do this, or is there a more effective and efficient way I should be looking at since in the end I'm not really coding an app and don't need all the other fancy bells and whistles incorporated into the APIs?

Any help is greatly appreciated since I'm a relatively novice coder (took a few classes in college, switched my major to English, got a job in a creative field, and now offered them coding skills I'm not exactly sure I still have :).

```py
import openpyxl
import requests
import base64

# Spotify API credentials
CLIENT_ID = (not posting these here haha)
CLIENT_SECRET = ""

# Function to get an access token from Spotify
def get_access_token():
    url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
    credentials = f'{CLIENT_ID}:{CLIENT_SECRET}'
    encoded_credentials = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Basic {encoded_credentials}'}
    data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
    response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    return response.json()['access_token']

# Function to get song popularity from Spotify
def get_song_popularity(song_uri, access_token):
    if song_uri is None:
        return None
    
    song_id = song_uri.split(':')[-1]  # Extract the last part of the URI as the song ID
    url = f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/{song_id}'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    
    if 'popularity' in data:
        return data['popularity']
    else:
        return None

# Function to process the Excel file and update with song popularity
def process_excel(excel_file_path):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
    ws = wb.active

    access_token = get_access_token()

    # Adding a new column header
    ws.cell(row=1, column=4, value='Popularity')

    for row_idx, cell in enumerate(ws['C'][1:], start=2):  # Assuming URIs are in column A starting from the second row
        song_uri = cell.value
        song_popularity = get_song_popularity(song_uri, access_token)
        
        if song_popularity is not None:
            ws.cell(row=row_idx, column=4, value=song_popularity)

    wb.save(excel_file_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    excel_file_path = 'streams.xlsx'
    process_excel(excel_file_path)
```

(SpotifyAPI annoyingly does not let you access raw song streams, but rather a "popularity index" which is an integer from 0-100 which ironically uses streams somewhere in the algorithm to obtain the final number, but I guess Spotify just wants to be as convoluted as possible. So side point, but if anyone has ideas on how to access streams directly please let me know).

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is provided typically via paid 3rd party services, such as [Chartmetric](https://chartmetric.com) or [Soundcharts](https://soundcharts.com/datasources), which do all the daily scraping & aggregation etc. for you. Like you mentioned, most official APIs do not tend to provide raw streams publicly.